# .NET Core EF, cleaning up SqlConnection.CreateCommand

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET Core DI to get `DbContext` and in my logic I need to execute raw SQL commands also on DB, so for that purpose I am creating `DbCommand` to execute SQL like this(just an example query, actual one is little complex so not writing here for simplicity):

```
public string GetId()
{
    var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();

    bool isOpen = cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open;
    if (!isOpen)
    {
         cmd.Connection.Open();
    }

    cmd.CommandText = "Select TOP 1 ID from ABC;";
    var result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (isOpen)
    {
         cmd.Connection.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

My question here is, that I am using `GetDbConnection()` and `CreateCommand()` on DbContext, so Do I need to explicitly dispose result of any of those commands(or enclose those in `using` statement)?

Also the `if` block to check if `cmd.Connection.State` is `ConnectionState.Open` required, if DI is providing with DbContext, that connection will already be open?

BTW we are using `AddDbContextPool` to register `DbContext` to enable `DbContext` pooling if that matters.

Comment: The context should be disposed after running this method which probably means: the object containing `GetId()`.

Comment: @Gert I believe the code should be written in a way which is independent of the lifetime of the object. All EF (Core) methods follow the same principle, I don't see a reason user code not doing the same.

Comment: In this particular case I was wondering: why use the context's connection? Why not create (& dispose) a new one borrowing the context's connection _string_. Anyway, good to explain that the context's connection is used here.

Comment: Here is the EF Core [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/v2.2.6/src/EFCore.Relational/Storage/Internal/RelationalCommand.cs#L142) for a similar task. The only difference is that the `IRelationalConnection` wrapper uses counting for `Open` / `Close`, hence they don't need to check the state. And they keep the connection open only if the method returns opened `DbReader`, which I'm sure will call close as part of its `Dispose`.

Comment: As a side note, if they have exposed publicly some more flexible `ExecuteSqlCommand` method (allowing controlling the `CommandType` for instance, and `ExecuteScalar` / `ExecuteReader` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`), there won't be a need of writing such user code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> My question here is, that I am using `GetDbConnection()` and `CreateCommand()` on DbContext, so Do I need to explicitly dispose result of any of those commands(or enclose those in using statement)?

These are different, and the answer is yes for the later, no for the former.

All you need is to follow to simple principle - the code which allocates resource is responsible for cleaning it up.

`GetDbConnection` (as indicated by the word `Get`) does not create `DbConnection` object, but returns the one created and used by the `DbContext` instance during its lifetime. In this case the `DbContext` owns the `DbConnection`, so you shouldn't dispose that object (doing so could break the owner functionality).

From the other side, `CreateCommand` *does* create new `DbCommand` object, so now your code is owning it and is responsible for disposing it when not needed anymore.

The same principle applies to `Open` / `Close`. Again, your code is not owning the `DbConnection` object, so you have to leave it in the same state as it was when you retrieved it. EF Core internally does that when processing commands which need open connection - open it at the beginning, close it when done. Except if it was opened externally, in which case they do nothing. Which is exactly the aforementioned principle - if your code does `Open`, then it should do `Close`, do nothing otherwise.

So the code in question should be something like this (note that there is a bug in close logic of your code - the condition for calling `Close` should be `!isOpen`, the same used for `Open` call):

```
public string GetId()
{
    using (var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        bool wasOpen = cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open;
        if (!wasOpen) cmd.Connection.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "Select TOP 1 ID from ABC;";
            var result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!wasOpen) cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG! You help me find a race condition which was in code for years.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to use the `using` statement so it will automatically dispose of the object when you no longer need it.

However, in your scenario, if you are using this as part of a web application, I believe that the _context scope will be created and disposed off after every HTTP Request, so it will automatically dispose any objects created within the _context scope.